# Why does Json.Dumps escape single quotes and how to avoid?

Tags: javascript, python, json

See the following code:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = "idx_vol i.e.(('uvolr', '>=', 80))"
>>> json.dumps(s)

'"idx_vol i.e.((\'uvolr\', \'>=\', 80))"'
```

This presents a problem because im trying to send some data that can then be parsed using javascript JSON.parse in to a valid json object. However, that function fails with the above string.

Im trying to understand why json.dumps does this and how to resolve (without having to do a string replace if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't - it's your python repl that's adding the escapes:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = "idx_vol i.e.(('uvolr', '>=', 80))"
>>> json.dumps(s)
'"idx_vol i.e.((\'uvolr\', \'>=\', 80))"'
>>> print(json.dumps(s))
"idx_vol i.e.(('uvolr', '>=', 80))"
```

Comment: I agree. If you save the str into a JSON file and open it in the text editor, you will see the str is exactly as specified.

Comment: interesting because when this string is passed to a web page or rendered using flask tags for instance, those escape characters are written.

Comment: fyi..the only, but sucky way, i was able to avoid having those escaped characters written to a flask rendered page was to use eval(json.dumps(s))